# Problemas instalando Prestashop - Digital Ocean

Tags: prestashop, digitalocean

Tengo una base de datos (cluster) y un droplet en Digital Ocean, los cuales se comunican sin problemas.

Trate de instalar Prestashop en el droplet, pero este fallo al 12% de avanzado. Al tratar de revisar que pudo suceder, obtuve este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve revisando en google por el error y como poder solucionarlo y no obtuve resultados, por lo que apelo a su ayuda para ver que puede estar sucediendo o si a lo mejor el cluster de Digital Ocean tenga algun limitante que este causando esto.